# Act as Votable for nested Resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie on rails and have created a listings and reviews app, (yelp type) and I want users to vote on the reviews, I have installed act as votable and configured as below but I seem to be missing something... any ideas why am getting that error?

Below is my routes.rb

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :listings do
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index, :upvote, :downvote] do
      resources :user do
        put "upvote", to: "reviews#upvote"
        put "downvote", to: "reviews#downvote"
      end
    end
  end

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/how'

  get 'pages/faqs'

  get 'pages/contact'

  get 'pages/privacy'

  get 'pages/tos'

  get 'pages/guidelines'

  root 'listings#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Here is my show.html.erb, I will turn it into a partial when it works

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= image_tag @listing.image_url (:medium) %>
      <h3><%= @listing.name %></h3>
        <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= @avg_rating  %> ></div>
          <p class="small"><%= "#{@reviews.length} reviews" %></p>
          <address>
            <strong>Address:</strong>
            <%= @listing.address %><br>
            <strong>Phone:</strong>
            <%= @listing.phone %><br>
            <strong>Email:</strong>
            <%= mail_to @listing.email %> <br>
            <strong>Website:</strong>
            <%= link_to @listing.website, @listing %>
          </address>
        <hr>
          <p>
            <strong>About:</strong>
            <p><%= h(@listing.description).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %></p>
          </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <%= link_to "Haiya, Post a Review ", new_listing_review_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-info" %> <br><br>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-md-3"></th>
              <th class="col-md-9"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>           
          <tbody>
             <% if @reviews.blank? %>
             <tr>
              <p>No reviews yet. Be the first to write one!</p>
            <% else %>
                <% @reviews.each do |review| %>              
                    <td>
                      <h4> <%= "#{review.user.first_name.capitalize} #{review.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}." %></h4>
                      <p class = "small"><%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago </p>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                      <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= review.rating %> ></div>
                      <p><%= h(review.comment).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %></p>

                      <%= link_to 'UP', listing_review_user_upvote_path(@listing, review), method: :put %>

                      <!-- Check if user is signed in, to enable edit and update -->
                      <% if user_signed_in? %>
                      <% if (review.user == current_user) || (current_user.admin?) %>
                      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_listing_review_path(@listing, review), class: "text-left"  %>
                      <%= link_to "Delete", listing_review_path(@listing, review), method: :delete, class: "text-left"  %>     
                      <% end %>
                    <% end %>

                </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </tbody>

        </table>
  </div>
</div>
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_listing_path(@listing), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', listings_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>

<!--The script for star ratings. -->

<script>
  $('.star-rating').raty({
    path: 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bebuwaphotos/uploads/stars',
    readOnly: true,
    score: function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is my reviews controller

```html
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! 
  before_action :set_listing
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote, :downvote]
  before_action :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  #Added the def upvote and downvote
  def upvote
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    @review.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end


  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.listing_id = @listing.id

    respond_to do |format|
        if @review.save
          format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Your review was successfully posted.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|

      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listing_path(@listing), notice: 'Your Review was successfully destroyed :(.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    #Check user

     def check_user
      unless (@review.user == current_user) || (current_user.admin?)
        redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, this review belongs to someone else, you can only edit reviews you have posted."
      end
    end


    #set listing

    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end
   
end
```

And my model :

```html
class Review < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :listing
 validates :rating, :comment, presence: true
   validates :rating, numericality: {
     only_integer: true,
     greater_than_or_equal_to: 1,
     less_than_or_equal_to: 5,
     message: "You have to select at least 1 star if not more stars.."
     }

 acts_as_votable 
           
end
```

Finally here is my error

[image]

Please explain like you would to a newbie.. or a 5 year old .

Thank you Eshan, followed your answer and got the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are doing well as a newbie.
2. The first thing you do when you get an error related to routes, you run `rails routes` in commandline, so you can see your routes in front of you :

[image]

### Problem:

You are having a problem with `listing_review_user_upvote` path, which leads to `/listings/:listing_id/reviews/:review_id/user/:user_id/upvote(.:format)` URI pattern as you see above.

This route needs three params: **listing_id**, **review_id**, and **user_id**, but you call it this way in your view:

`listing_review_user_upvote_path(@listing, review)`.

You don't send **user_id** at all, meanwhile you don't even need it since you use **current_user** in your controller's action.

### Solution:

I suggest you to update your routes to be:

```ruby
resources :listings do
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index] do
      put "upvote", to: "reviews#upvote"
      put "downvote", to: "reviews#downvote"
      resources :user
    end
end
```

And to use it in your view this way, with ids instead of objects :

`listing_review_user_upvote_path(@listing.id, review.id)`

These two steps will resolve your problem hopefully.

Finally, `except` option is used with resources to avoid generating some of its CRUD routes like: `update`, `index`, `edit`, you don't need to use it with your custom routes like: `upvote` and `downvote`.

### Update:

- You should use the correct param in your controller, `review_id` rather than `id`, change `review = Review.find(params[:id])` to `review = Review.find(params[:review_id])`
- I suggest you to use `find_by(id: params[:review_id` rather than `find(params[:review_id` because find method raises an exception if it couldn't find the object in db.

---

Comment: Thank you @Ehsan, I'm extremely encouraged. Please look at the updated error message I get..

Comment: One more problem :(. Seems that I can only vote for one review, votes on any other reviews only affect the first review .. any clue?

Comment: Sorted that out, I had missed out something on my code.